# Paypal Array returning success message but payment not getting process i am using laravel and express-checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

PayPal retuning me the success array but the payment not getting ** processed**   please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkESp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the classic express checkout API? That is almost 20 years old. You should be using the v2/checkout/orders API, with the [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK) or similar. See the information and links for a server integration within [Set up standard payments.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/)

The problem with your "payment not getting processed" is that no payment has been executed or captured. After payer approval, it is required to execute a `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API call (classic API) -- or similarly with the current API, an orders capture API call.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I am using the updated package. here is a referral link you can check https://www.larablocks.com/package/srmklive/paypal 
here is the screenshot link.  https://prnt.sc/1ygt3v4

Comment: It is a package for a very old API.